# How to get the timestamps of lyrics in songs?

Tags: python, audio, voice-recognition, genius-api, musixmatch

We have built an application in Python for getting the lyrics of a song that the user searches for. We are using the Genius API for this. However, we also want to know the timestamps of each lyric in the song, so that we know when each lyric plays or shows up. Is there an API or library that we could use to get the timestamp of each lyric? Or would we need to manually recognize each lyric in the song using an audio recognition technique?

Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last time I looked, Genius Lyrics' APIs do not include timestamps unfortunately. There are alternatives out there, such as Musixmatch - although they're not free (and apparently not cheap).
I did find [Lyrics Plus](https://github.com/khanhas/spicetify-cli/tree/master/CustomApps/lyrics-plus) though. It's an integration for Spotify. Maybe their code on GitHub could help. Good luck!